# expect argument char in C with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, char, scanf

hi i have  this  script in C i compile with gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

but return

```
warning: format ‘%[0-9 ’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[1]’ [-Wformat=]
  92 |     sscanf(resultato,"%[0-9 ]",&SecondPart);
     |                       ~~~~~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~
     |                            |   |
     |                            |   char (*)[1]
     |                            char *
```

or  when not return error (because i modify the script ) not  return nothing
the script

```
RING_FUNC(ring_binapiceckservertime)
{
    char Address[100] = {0};
    const char *UrlSpec = "/time";
    char *FirstPart[30] = {0};
    char SecondPart[] = "";
    size_t sz = strlen(cmDOriG)  + strlen(UrlApi)+ strlen(UrlApiV3) + strlen(UrlSpec)  + 1;
    char destination[sz];
    strcpy(destination, cmDOriG);
    strcat(destination, UrlApi);
    strcat(destination, UrlApiV3);
    strcat(destination, UrlSpec);
    //printf("%s\n", destination);
    //int  status = system(destination);
    const char* mode = "r";
    FILE *cmd=popen(destination, mode);
    char result[50]={0x0};
    //while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd) !=NULL)
    const char *resultato = fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd);
         //  printf("%s\n", resultato);
       
    sscanf(resultato,"%[0-9 ]",&SecondPart);
    pclose(cmd);
       // 
        printf("%s\n", &SecondPart[13]);
          printf("value of b_static: %.*s\n", (int)sizeof(SecondPart), SecondPart);
}
```

if  i set

````
printf("%s\n", &SecondPart); or printf("%s\n", SecondPart)```
not  give me  error but not return nothing
````

Comment: Basically you are trying do a lot of semi-advanced stuff before you have grasped the basics of arrays and strings in C. I'm guessing you are coming from another programming language. Notably, C does not have a string class like most languages do. So you need to study arrays, then pointers, then strings, in that order.

Comment: Thanks for answer Lundin , yes  your  intuition is correct , and  i study also C too, but Learning for me is never so linear , like  study pointer and array , and after, resolve problem ,  in practice one thing is to study and one thing to be aware of what you do, so therfore I'm here thanks again for your time bye

Comment: String handling in C is a very common pitfall from people coming from higher level languages like Java etc. Most C programming books are structured in a linear fashion so that you learn all pre-requisites before moving on. You can't understand pointers before you understand arrays, and you can't understand strings before you understand arrays and pointers both.

Answer (score 1):

strings in the `scanf` family of functions are handled differently to other data types. You don't need to pass in a pointer to them as they are already a pointer. So all you need is

```
sscanf(resultato,"%[0-9 ]",SecondPart);
```

But! That won't work because SecondPart isn't large enough to hold anything except an empty string as that is all the space you've allocated.

You need to specify the size of it like this...

```
char SecondPart[100];
```

...but this is making asssumptions that the largest string being entered is 99 characters long.

A better way since you can examine the contents of `resultato` is to calculate the length of the string you're going to need first.

```
char *SecondPart;
size_t length = strspn(resultato, "01234567890 ");
SecondPart = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length+1)); // Note sizeof(char) is pretty much guarenteed to be 1, but it makes the code clearer what you're allocating.
sscanf(resultato, "%[0-9 ]", SecondPart);
```

allocating memory does mean that at some point later you will need to `free` the memory of course.

```
free(SecondPart);
```

Comment: thanks  so much Chriss  for  your  answer very comprehensive , for  a newbbie like me , i insert  char SecondPart[100];   and   sscanf(resultato,"%[0-9 ]",SecondPart);  but unfortunally not return nothing , i suppose probably sscanf not  like  result of  fgets?? if i print resultato i have  simply string {timestamp:12345678996326}, i suppose  with 100 char is  sufficients :D, but  probably this sscanf  have  somthing strange , thanks  again for your  time

Comment: @armanvanlendel now sounds like a good time to investigate using a debugger, so you can see what your code is doing as it happens.

Comment: yes i suppose yes ....... ........how to use a debugger ?? :D

Comment: @armanvanlendel google should be able to answer that for your build setup